# How to hard code value to property variable when instance of class is created?

Tags: c#, .net

I am specifically creating a simple To Do app in C#. I have a public property in my "Item" class called "DateTimeCreated". I would like the current date/time to be set at the moment the new "Item" is created. I removed the relevant mark-up from the Create and Edit cshtml pages as I don't wish for it to be created or edited, but rather stamped when an instance of the Item class is created.
Part of my Item class I have...

```
public DateTime DateTimeCreated
{
get
{
Return DateTimeCreated;
}
set
{
DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.now;
DateTimeCreated = timeStamp;
}
}
```

I get no errors when running the app, but as soon as I click "Create" in order to submit the creation of a new "Item", the browser crashes. And if I change it to simply

```
public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
```

the browser doesn't crash but the value is the default DateTime.now value of 01/01/0001 01:02 or something to that effect
Am I doing this right but need a tweak or is my approach all wrong?

Comment: `return DateTimeCreated;` and `DateTimeCreated = timeStamp;` are recursive, because you're referring back to the same property. Perhaps you want `public dateTime DateTimeCreated { get; }  = DateTime.Now;` (or `get;set;` if you want to allow changes).

Comment: `public DateTime DateTimeCreated{ get; set; } = DateTime.Now;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the second property to this

```
public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

and if the property only needs to be set once at creation time of the object you can remove the `set` as well like so

```
public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; } = DateTime.Now;
```